# how to apply a function based on a condition to individual column in df.groupby.agg()

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I code mostly in R but I want to improve my python skills so now I do my analysis in python. When working with a data frame in R I would constantly make a new summarized dataframe with group_by and summarize. I am trying to do this in python with `df.groupby().agg()`  However I'm finding the process difficult. For example, in R I could apply functions and conditions to individual columns in `summarize()`. I could also build off a new column just created in the previous line of code inside of summarize. I find this actually really cool what one can do in R.

Anyways how can I apply a function to an individual column like `mean()` where a certain condition is met in another column? The following code shows how to do this in R and my attempt in python.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(user_id) %>%
       summarize(avg_parking_duration = mean(duration[type == "parking"]),
                 avg_reservation_duration =  mean(duration[type == "reservation"])
)
```

The code above would group the data frame of parking transactions by user_id. It would then calculate the average parking duration from the column duration where the column type == "parking". Likewise the same is done for the duration of transactions of the type "reservation".

all that I have seen online for python is something like this

```
df.groupby('user_id').agg(
        avg_parking_duration = ('duration','mean')
    )

or


df.groupby('user_id').agg(
        avg_parking_duration = ('duration',lambda x: x.mean())
    )
```

I don't know unfortunately how to apply a condition then specifically to duration based on another column type. How do you go about this?

Please note I do **not** want to filter out first the data frame by type parkings or reservations before the `agg()` because I would like to create new multiple columns with different functions inside of `agg()` and I would need the filtered out information.

#### dataset

```
data = {'user_id': [u1, u1,u1,u1, u2, u2,u2,u2], 'type': ['parking', 'parking', 'reservation', 'reservation','parking', 'parking', 'reservation', 'reservation'],'duration': [43,60,20,23,143,290,25,15]}
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please note I do not want to filter out first the data frame by type parkings or reservations before the agg()

It is problematic. Because [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) working with each column separately, so cannot filter `type` and get mean of `duration` together.

Solution with helper column `park` and used for `mean` or hacky filtering original DataFrame per groups - both same ouput:

Solution with helper columns before `groupby.agg`:

```
df = (df.assign(park = df["duration"].where(df["type"] == 'parking'),
                res = df["duration"].where(df["type"] == 'reservation'))
       .groupby('user_id').agg(avg_parking_duration = ('park','mean'),
                               avg_reservation_duration =('res','mean')
      ))
print (df)
         avg_parking_duration  avg_reservation_duration
user_id                                                
1                        51.5                      21.5
2                       216.5                      20.0
```

Hacky way:

```
#necessary unique values in index
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

f = lambda x: x.where(df.loc[x.index, "type"] == 'parking').mean()
f1 = lambda x: x.where(df.loc[x.index, "type"] == 'reservation').mean()

df = (df.groupby('user_id').agg(avg_parking_duration = ('duration',f),
                               avg_reservation_duration = ('duration',f1)
      ))
print (df)
         avg_parking_duration  avg_reservation_duration
user_id                                                
1                        51.5                      21.5
2                       216.5                      20.0
```

Comment: A pivot followed by a mean, and renaming could be a simpler option

Comment: @sammywemmy Yop, but OP requirement is `df.groupby.agg`, so only it was used.